# OpenAI Python API Rate Limiting Issue

Tags: python, openai-api, rate-limiting

[image]I am using OpenAI's Python API and I am getting a rate limiting error despite making any requests. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

This is the code that I am using:

```
import openai
openai.api_key = ""
messages = [ {"role": "system", "content": "You are an intelligent assistant."} ]

message = input("User : ")
if message:
    messages.append(
        {"role": "user", "content": message},
    )
    chat = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613", messages=messages
    )
reply = chat.choices[0].message.content
print(f"ChatGPT: {reply}")
messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": reply})
```

Please note that I am using a valid API key.

When I run the program I receive this error:
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.

On my OpenAI account it shows that I have not made any requests this month.

What could be the issue here?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens when you send the same request via `curl`?

Comment: Maybe try generating a new key in https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys ?